# Change the font style inside *modifier{text} in xypic

Tags: xy-pic

I'm trying to create a tree structure using "xypic" package.
Everything is ok except that when I write something inside

```
*modifier{text}
```

the default font used for labeling in xypic is not used. Instead the default font of the document is used. How to change this setting ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
& Start \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr] & &\\
Font & is & different \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr]\\
& E \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & F & G\\
G \ar[dr] & & {}\save[]+<1.5cm,-0.7cm>*\txt<10pc>{%
This is a very long text here. How to change this ?} \restore\\
& I & &\\
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

Just tell LaTeX what font you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
& \textit{Start} \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr] & &\\
\textit{Font} & \textit{is} & \textit{different} \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr]\\
& E \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & F & G\\
G \ar[dr] & & {}\save[]+<1.5cm,-0.7cm>*\txt<10pc>{%
\normalfont\sffamily
This is a very long text here. How to change this?} \restore\\
& I & &\\
}
\end{document}
```

I've used `\sffamily`, but it can be any set of font changing declarations. With `\normalfont` you ensure to be in the "initial state".

Note also `\textit{...}` around the textual entries in the nodes, to get the font right. Also there you can use something like

```
\textnormal{<font declarations>Start}
```

[image]

If you are using the Lucida fonts, then this might be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lucimatx}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\newcommand{\xtextit}[1]{\textnormal{\itshape #1}}
\newcommand{\xitshape}{\normalfont\itshape}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
& \xtextit{Start} \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr] & &\\
\xtextit{Font} & \xtextit{is} & \xtextit{different} \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr]\\
& E \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & F & G\\
G \ar[dr] & & {}\save[]+<1.5cm,-0.7cm>*\txt<10pc>{%
\linespread{1.1}\xitshape
This is a very long text here. How to change this?} \restore\\
& I & &\\
}
\end{document}
```

The commands `\xtextit` and `\xitshape` are just to ensure that the chosen font is selected, independently of the context. Possibly `\textit` and `\itshape` are sufficient. The `\linespread{1.1}` can be unnecessary if you load scaled down Lucida fonts. (I don't have `lucidabr.sty`, which is old; I only own the last Type1 version of the Lucida fonts, which uses `lucimatx.sty.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I want the same font as used in the start of the tree. It is XYATIP- Medium and XYBTIP-Medium. Problem is I don't I don't know how to set these fonts

Comment: xyatip and xybtip don't contain characters: they only have arrow tips.

Comment: Now I got it. If you use Lucidabr package, the fonts doesn't match, in case of Computer Modern fonts, its the same. Just one more thing, which of the font you think it is as in the "Start" word ?

LucidaBright-Italic (Type1) or LucidaNewMath-AltItalic (Type1)

Comment: @RupsDell Can you add to your question a complete minimal example with the font packages you load?

Comment: @RupsDell I don't have `lucidabr`, but with the more recent `lucimatx` I get the default math italic font for "Start" (which is not recommended, particularly in "different"). Better use `\textnormal{\itshape Start}` and saying something like `\linespread{1.1}\normalfont\itshape` when starting the content of `\txt`.